# How to communicate with ViewModel from Model

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am quit new to MVVM. So please correct me if I am doing any mistake in implementing MVVM.

In my Model class there are two properties Price and IsChecked.

```
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public static int _total;

    bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {

        get
        {
            return _isChecked;

        }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;

            if (value == true)
            {
                _total+= this.Price;
            }
            else
            {
                _total-= this.Price;
            }


        }
    }
```

In My ViewModel Class there is a property of Type List <Model > and it is bounded to datagrid in view and another property is Total, which bounded to a textBlock in View.

```
    public int Total
    {
        get
        {
            return  DocumentStoreModel._total;

        }
        set
        {

        }

    }
```

DataGrid has a checkBox column and it is bounded with Ischecked property

```
<DG:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Select" Binding="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ></DG:DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Now, if user checked the Checkbox from checkbox column in DataGrid then total should be reflected in View.

My ViewModel class is implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

My qus is,if my model's property is changing how i can tell it to my viewModel ?

please let me know How i can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are exposing your Model within your `ViewModel`, then you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your Model. You however have a problem in that your Total property is static and (afaik) you cant use `INotifyPropertyChanged` for static properties.
I would suggest you create a custom event on your model that can be subscribed to on your `ViewModel`. Here's an example (you might want to tidy it up a bit).

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    internal static event EventHandler TotalChanged;
    internal static int Total { get; private set;}

    private int price;
    public int Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set
        {
            price = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Price"));
        }
    }

    private bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {  isChecked = value; 
            if (value)
                Total += Price;
            else
                Total -= Price;
            if (TotalChanged != null)
                TotalChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
        }
    }
}

public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public int Total
    {
        get { return Model.Total;  }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Model.TotalChanged += TotalChanged;
    }

    private void TotalChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Total"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dean,                                                       I used same approch. only difference was instead of using event I used delegate. I was not sure about Whether this approch is according to MVVM or not, thats why i asked the qus. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell your ViewModel's `Total` property is pointing to your Model's `Total` property so any changes you make to the Model's total will essentially be changed for the ViewModel as well.

What you might have to do though is raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Total` property on the ViewModel when `IsChecked` is changed. This will tell your View to update the data for your total text block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a `Command` (by implementing `ICommand` or variants of it) and expose as **property** on the ViewModel and **bind** it on the view for the event on the checkbox.